# SNOWFLAKE SQL GROUP BY column and SUM a column base on unique values of another column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a table that looks like so:

| ID | QTY | TRACKER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | aa2 |
| 123 | 44 | hg3 |
| 123 | 1 | ss4 |
| 333 | 2 | dd2 |
| 333 | 2 | dd2 |

I want to group this by ID then SUM the QTY but only by the unique tracker values.

So that my end result looks like this:

| ID | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 48 |
| 333 | 2 |

Comment: And what should the result look like if row five has a quantity of 3 rather than 2? Would the desired output be: `333    5` or `333   2` or `333   3` or ???

Comment: no it would be 2 because tracker is the same and it came first.

Comment: Please elaborate. So your rows 4 and 5... Both have an ID of 333, and both have a tracker of dd2. Now re-imagine these two rows, where one has a QTY of 2, and the other a QTY of 3. Why would you pick 3 over 2, or vice versa, etc? In a table, there is no concept of "came first" unless you have a column such as timestamp or something else that logically indicates which came first.

Comment: it doesn't matter which one I pick I suppose, all that matters is the sum function only activates when tracker is different. So for your example even if the qty is 2 for row 4, 3 on row 5, it can either return 2 or 3. I chose 2 just because it came one more before 3 qty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly have duplicate data, then you can select `distinct` values and then wrap your query.

```
select id, sum(qty) as qty
from (
  select distinct id, qty, tracker
  from yourtable
  )
group by id
```

However, per my recent comments above, what is your expected output if rows 4 and 5 have different QTY values (but the same ID and Tracker values)? Depending on how you answer that question, then this answer may need to be updated.

**UPDATE**

Based on your answer to the comment, then you could write however you want to choose the value. Here I simply use `min(qty)` to pick one. Since you don't have a timestamp, date, or other column used for ordering events in time, then the concept of "which came first" **does not exist**. There is no order in tables.

```
select id, sum(qty) as qty 
from (
  select id, tracker, min(qty) as qty
  from yourtable
  group by id, tracker
  )
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the (somewhat arbitrary) first row for each id/tracker combination, and then GROUP BY.

```
select id, sum(qty)
from
(
  select y.*, row_number() over (partition by id, tracker) rn
  from yourtable y
) dt
where rn = 1
group by id
```